# Is 1kb 1000bits or 1024bits

Tags: memory, 64-bit, rom

I'm super confused about this relatively easy conversion.

Is 1kb=1000 bits or 1024 bits?

I realise that 1024 bits would be represented by 1Kibibit or 1Kibit and not 1kb but I see many many people using 1kb as 1024 bits and no one using 1Kibit. This causes a lot confusion when I'm solving problems related to size of rom, etc.

Could someone please tell me if 1kb is 1000 or 1024 bits?

Comment: If you are talking about bandwidth, then `Kb` refers to 1,000 bits, `Mb` refers to 1,000,000 bits, `Gb` refers to 1,000,000,000 bits, etc. For example, in ethernet standards: 10Base-T is 10 Mbps (10,000,000), 100Base-TX is 100 Mbps (100,000,000), and 1000Base-T is 1 Gbps (1,000,000,000). For WAN cirduits, the old 56K (56,000) and 64K (64,000). T1 lines have 24 individual 64K timeslots, giving you 1.536 Mbps (1,536,000).

Comment: No, not bandwidth. I'm talking about memory sizes like ROM, RAM, cache, etc

Comment: OK, you did not specify, and that is something that really confuses people about networks. They assume it is like RAM where 1K is 1024, but for circuits, 1K is 1000.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Size of files in Windows OS. (It's KB or kB?)](https://superuser.com/questions/938234/size-of-files-in-windows-os-its-kb-or-kb)

Answer (score 0):

A [kibibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte) AKA 'KiB' is 2^10 bytes; therefore a kibibit AKA 'kib' is 2^10 bits.

A kilobyte AKA 'KB' is a thousand bytes; a kilobit AKA 'kb' is 1,000 bits. Kilo is an [ISU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) or 'SI' standard prefix for 'a thousand'.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about memory sizes (ROM, RAM, CPU cache, etc.) it will be 1024 bits, because of the way the memory cells are organized. Only when it gets to harddisks (also flash devices) it's actually the base 10 value for historical reasons and marketing purposes.

Also see this nice [answer](https://superuser.com/a/938259/990044) (and xkcd comic).