# How can I change the Windows 10 file system's display from kibi/mebi/gibi to kilo/mega/giga?

Tags: windows-10, filesystems

Windows displays file sizes in powers of 1024, known as kibibytes (KiB), mebibytes (MiB), gibibytes (GiB), etc. However, the abbreviations it uses are for the powers of 1000, known as kilobytes (kB), megabytes (MB), gigabytes (GB), etc. This behavior is shown in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbOAe.png).

How can I change the displayed value from the powers of 1024 (391 mibibytes, in the image) to the powers of 1000 (410 megabytes)? If it is not possible to do so natively, is there a piece of software that can do it? If it is not possible to do so at all, is it possible to change the displayed abbreviation from the incorrect format (MB, in the image) to the correct format (MiB)?

---

**Additional information:**

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/938259/1500367) gives some explanation as to why Microsoft may have chosen the powers of 1024 over the powers of 1000, but I already understand the debate. I simply prefer the powers of 1000 and would like Windows 10 to accommodate that preference. It's much easier for me to do mental math in base-10 than in base-2. More importantly, I need to remind myself every time that what I'm seeing is actually a different unit of measurement than it appears to be, lest I make an incorrect judgement about the size.

Comment: Well there is exactly 40 years (since 1981) that is what Windows do. No one will change it.

Comment: You can write a column handler that will slows down Explorer. It is advanced programming. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/column-handlers to solve your problem.